# Issuing a single-session certificate for WCF... dangers/ issues?

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption, certificate

I'm trying to design a WCF access pattern that will allow me to secure a publicly exposed service containing potentially sensitive information.

I like the idea of using certificates to encrypt and protect traffic from client to server, but I'm not a fan of pre-issuing the certificates, or having them generated by a third party that I would have to pay for... managing a revocation list seems overkill, but I don't want to compromise security.

My current idea is to implement some sort of 2-part authentication method that would return a generated-on-the-fly certificate that was good for a single day, and use that for all other WCF communications.  The client would have the service's public certificate installed when the client was installed, and would encrypt the payload with the service's public certificate, and sign it with the generated client certificate (for all messages except the authentication request).  It seems like the right way to do this, but I haven't seen any sort of discussion along those lines anywhere.

Is this because the method is inherently insecure, (if so, how), impractical, or slow, or  not supported in the WCF framework?  Or is my Google-fu weak and there's lots of articles about this?